# How to get the elapsed time of a .NET WebAPI call

Tags: c#, datetime, logging, asp.net-web-api

How can I get the elapsed time for a `.NET WebAPI` call within C#?

I need such information for my log file

I could easily do a `DateTime.Now()` just before and after the api call, however, if there is something already made... let's use it!

Comment: I think "Elapsed time" concept refers to `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`. How about using `Stopwatch` class with it's `ElapsedMilliseconds` property instead?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use filter

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace App.Utility
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to log requests to server
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class LogActionRequestsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public LogActionRequestsAttribute()
        {
             //You can inject to constructors ILog or what ever
        }

        public static Stopwatch GetTimer(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            const string key = "__timer__";
            if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return (Stopwatch)request.Properties[key];
            }

            var result = new Stopwatch();
            request.Properties[key] = result;
            return result;
        }
        
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            
            var timer = GetTimer(actionContext.Request);
            timer.Start();
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            var timer = GetTimer(actionExecutedContext.Request);
            timer.Stop();
            var totalTime = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;            
        }
    }
}
```

Then in webapi config

```
config.Filters.Add(
                (LogActionRequestsAttribute)
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof (LogActionRequestsAttribute)));
```

AttributeUsage prevent calling attribute twice.
But i think other option could be yo write http module to use begin, end request events which is probably the best and precise measurements, in my app its enough to use attributes since few milliseconds would not make a big deal for me

Comment: this works well but I find if there's an unhandled exception then OnActionExecuted never gets called, so I lose the timing for that method. Something to keep in mind, if you only need successful calls that's fine, otherwise you need to look at implementing an ExceptionHandler.

Comment: Why would the call to `GetService` when registering the filter result in `null`?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone, I've added an updated version of Vova's answer below that works for .NET Core.

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to log requests to server
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class LogActionRequestsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string ACTION = "Action";
    private const string RESULT = "Result";

    private static Stopwatch GetTimer(HttpContext context, string type)
    {
        var key = $"__timer__{type}";
        if (context.Items.ContainsKey(key)) return (Stopwatch) context.Items[key];
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        context.Items[key] = stopWatch;
        return stopWatch;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var timer = GetTimer(context.HttpContext, ACTION);
        timer.Start();
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        var timer = GetTimer(context.HttpContext, ACTION);
        timer.Stop();

        var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<LogActionRequestsAttribute>>();
        logger.LogInformation($"{ACTION} call to {context.HttpContext.Request.Path} took {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var timer = GetTimer(context.HttpContext, RESULT);
        timer.Start();
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        var timer = GetTimer(context.HttpContext, RESULT);
        timer.Stop();

        var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<LogActionRequestsAttribute>>();
        logger.LogInformation($"{RESULT} call to {context.HttpContext.Request.Path} took {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}
```

This attribute can be applied directly to an ApiController with no additional registration.